# How can i display header only homepage in Magento?

Tags: magento

I want to display header only homepage.

How can i disable header other page?

Answer (score 0):

Hi If your website having one column layout then open the 1column.phtml file and 
replace this line

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('header') ?>
```

with this,

```
<?php  $page= Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getIdentifier();?>
<?php if($page=='home'){ ?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('header') ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want remove this  header `using xml` then follow below steps

step1:create `local.xml` under `app/design/frontend/yourpackage/yourtemplate/layout`

code of local.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">

<default>
    <reference name="root">
        <remove name="headerone"/>
    </reference>
</default>
    <cms_index_index >
    <reference name="root">
        <block type="page/html_header" name="header" as="header">
                <block type="page/template_links" name="top.links" as="topLinks"/>
                <block type="page/switch" name="store_language" as="store_language" template="page/switch/languages.phtml"/>
                <block type="core/text_list" name="top.menu" as="topMenu" translate="label">
                    <label>Navigation Bar</label>
                    <block type="page/html_topmenu" name="catalog.topnav" template="page/html/topmenu.phtml"/>
                </block>
                <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="top.container" as="topContainer" translate="label">
                    <label>Page Header</label>
                    <action method="setElementClass"><value>top-container</value></action>
                </block>
            </block>
    </reference>
    </cms_index_index>

</layout>
```

Step2:goto page.xml  under `app/design/frontend/yourpackage/yourtemplate/layout`

Find `<block type="page/html_header" name="header" as="header">`

change it to

```
<block type="page/html_header" name="headerone" as="headerone">
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this quite easily without any code changes by adding a `<remove />` line for the header block in your local.xml and then in the home page layout, adding the header block to the `home` page in CMS under `page layout` in the `design` tab.

Layout is quite powerful in making such a custom mod.